# Cannot find tape devices in linux

Tags: linux, backup

I want to use tape devices to backup in linux. But I can't find the information of that devices in /proc/scsi/scsi. The tape devices is Quantum Scalar i40 and the OS in cluster is Red Hat Enterprise Linux.
Below is some information.

[tape devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw1tJ.png)
    # uname -r
       2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
   Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago) 


# lsscsi
[0:0:0:0]    disk    HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   3.56  /dev/sda
[0:0:0:1]    disk    HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   3.56  /dev/sdb
[0:3:0:0]    storage HP       P840             3.56  -        

# cat /proc/scsi/scsi
Attached devices:
Host:scsi0 Channel: 03 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: HP       Model: P840             Rev: 3.56
  Type:   RAID                             ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: HP       Model: LOGICAL VOLUME   Rev: 3.56
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 01
  Vendor: HP       Model: LOGICAL VOLUME   Rev: 3.56
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05

# modinfo st
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64/kernel/drivers/scsi/st.ko alias:          scsi:t-0x01*
alias:          char-major-9-*
license:        GPL
description:    SCSI tape (st) driver
author:         Kai Makisara
srcversion:     AB519E7875D34CA8D8A68F0
depends:
vermagic:       2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           buffer_kbs:Default driver buffer size for fixed block mode   (KB; 32) (int)
parm:           max_sg_segs:Maximum number of scatter/gather segments to use (256) (int)
parm:           try_direct_io:Try direct I/O between user buffer and tape drive (1) (int)
parm:           try_rdio:Try direct read i/o when possible (int)
parm:           try_wdio:Try direct write i/o when possible (int) 

#dmesg
................omit............................
st 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi tape st0
st 1:0:0:0: st0: try direct i/o: yes (alignment 4 B)
osst :I: Tape driver with OnStream support version 0.99.4
osst :I: $Id: osst.c,v 1.73 2005/01/01 21:13:34 wriede Exp $
SCSI Media Changer driver v0.25
ch0: type #1 (mt): 0x1+1 [medium transport]
ch0: type #2 (st): 0x1000+39 [storage]
ch0: type #3 (ie): 0x10+0 [import/export]
ch0: type #4 (dt): 0x100+1 [data transfer]
ch0: dt 0x100: ID/LUN unknown
ch0: INITIALIZE ELEMENT STATUS, may take some time ...
ch0: ... finished
ch 1:0:0:1: Attached scsi changer ch0
................omit............................
st0: Block limits 1 - 8388608 bytes.
pci 0000:01:00.1: Invalid ROM contents
tun3: Disabled Privacy Extensions
st0: Error e0000 (driver bt 0x0, host bt 0xe).
 rport-1:0-0: blocked FC remote port time out: removing target and saving binding
st 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
st 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
st0: Error on write filemark.
................omit............................
```

How can I solve the issue? Thanks!

Comment: "tape commands" https://access.redhat.com/solutions/68115 → → # `mt -f /dev/st0   status` ... And "Linux specific SCSI tape device name: /dev/st[0-9]" → https://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/unix-linux-basic-tape-management-commands/

Comment: I have read them. But the key point is that I can't find the tape devices.   There is no /dev/st* in linux.  
`# mt -f /dev/st0 status  
/dev/st0: No such file or directory  `
`# ls -a /dev/st*  
/dev/stderr  /dev/stdin  /dev/stdout`

Comment: Right. I have no /dev/st* ... but have /dev/sg*  on "el6" . ... https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=centos+/dev/st → → https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193472/interacting-with-tape-library-on-centos-7-via-mtx

Comment: I have /dev/sg0 /dev/sg1 and /dev/sg2 on "el6", but none is tape devices.
`# ls -a /dev/sg*  
/dev/sg0  /dev/sg1  /dev/sg2`...
`# lsscsi --generic  
[0:0:0:0]    disk    HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   3.56  /dev/sda   /dev/sg1  
[0:0:0:1]    disk    HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   3.56  /dev/sdb   /dev/sg2  
[0:3:0:0]    storage HP       P840             3.56  -         /dev/sg0  `
 And I notice error message in dmesg: `st0: Error e0000 (driver bt 0x0, host bt 0xe).
 rport-1:0-0: blocked FC remote port time out: removing target and saving binding
st 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device`